# Access function in imported file

Tags: python, django

I want to extend Django model, but don't want to make my `models.py` too fat. I decided to place business logic to separated class and file, and inherit it in `models.py`.

I've got import error in my case.

`appname/models.py`:

```
from .models_bl.content import ContentBL

...

def upload_to_video(instance, filename):
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    name = uuid.uuid4().hex[:12]
    basename = name + ext
    return os.path.join('video', strftime("%Y-%m", gmtime()), basename)   

...


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Content(ContentBL):
    ...
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_video, blank=True)
    video_thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_video, blank=True)
    ...
```

`appname/models_bl/content.py`:

```
# not works (import error)
from appname.models import upload_to_video

...

class ContentBL(models.Model):


    def save(self, *args, **args):
        ...
        if video_changed:

            # works, but bad practice, I guess
            from appname.models import upload_to_video

            # need upload_to_video() from models.py HERE
            video_thumb_filename = upload_to_video('image.jpg')

            command = "ffmpeg -i %s -vframes 1 -f image2 %s"
            os.system(command % (self.video.path, video_thumb_filename))
            self.video_thumb = video_thumb_filename
        ...
```

What is the best way to make it work?

Comment: Do you have an "_\_init_\_.py" file in the models_bl folder? Also, it looks like you're going to have a circular reference. models.py wants to import a class from content.py, but content.py wants to import a function from models.py.

Comment: was your objective to make things as complicated as possible?

Comment: @e4c5 If you see it too complicated, please give me some ideas how to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: @dyagmin Yes, I understand that it is a circular import. But I need this function. What am I to do? May be another structure of code..

Comment: upload_to_video could be in its own separate file so you don't have to worry about the circular reference, both models would import from this new file. And be sure there's a _\_init_\_.py file in the folder.